# arithmetic expression involving command

Tags: macros

Simple question.  I would like to do this:

```
\newcommand{\scatterplotwidth}{0.5\linewidth}
....
\includegraphics[width=0.9\scatterplotwidth]{myfig}
```

Without the 0.9 it works.  Is there a way to have 0.9 times a command variable?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\newcommand{\scatterplotwidth}{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth\relax}`

Comment: Typically one would use `\newlength{\scatterplotwidth} ... \setlength{\scatterplotwidth}{0.5\linewidth}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can define `\scatterplotwidth` to behave like a dimension parameter that loads a fraction of the current `\linewidth` by

```
\newcommand{\scatterplotwidth}{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth\relax}
```

Then `\scatterplotwidth` will be legal anywhere a length is needed, for instance in

```
\includegraphics[width=0.9\scatterplotwidth]{myfig}
```

---

By the way, the suggested

```
\newlength{\scatterplotwidth}
\setlength{\scatterplotwidth}{0.5\linewidth}
```

would not give the same result, because the value of `\scatterplotwidth` would be fixed to the size of `\linewidth` at the moment when `\setlength` is executed.

A different strategy based on length parameters would be defining a new command:

```
\newlength{\scatterplotwidth}
\newcommand{\scatterplot}[2][1]{%
   \setlength{\scatterplotwidth}{0.5\linewidth}%
   \includegraphics[width=#1\scatterplotwidth]{#2}%
}
```

that will be used like

```
\scatterplot{myfig}
```

or

```
\scatterplot[0.9]{myfig}
```

In the former case, `0.5\linewidth` (with the *current* `\linewidth`) would be used, in the latter case, the scaling would be applied.